# Published PyPi package (with Poetry) missing files after installation

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have the following project:

```
| my-projectttttttt
│
├───dist
│       my_projectttttttt-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
│       my_projectttttttt-1.0.0.tar.gz
│
├───src
│   ├───my_projectttttttt
│   │       __init__.py
│   │       __main__.py
│   │
│   └───resources
│           my_projectttttttt.png
│
├───tests
│       test_my_project.py
|
│ LICENSE.md
│ pyproject.toml
│ README.md
```

and I am trying to publish it via Poetry on PyPi using this pyproject.toml file:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0", "poetry-dynamic-versioning"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "my-projectttttttt"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "The description of the package"
license = "MIT"
authors = ["George K. Wright"]
repository = "https://github.com/"
homepage = "https://github.com/"

packages = [
    { include = "my_projectttttttt", from = "src"},
]
include = [
    { path = "src/resources" },
]


[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.6"
requests="^2.28.1"


[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-projectttttttt = "my_projectttttttt.__main__:main"
```

When I build the project using `poetry build` the produced archive:

```
C:\my-projectttttttt\dist\my_projectttttttt-1.0.0.tar.gz\my_projectttttttt-1.0.0.tar\my_projectttttttt-1.0.0\src\
```

has both `my_projectttttttt` module and `resources` folder with the png in it, but when I publish it using `poetry publish` and then install it via pip using `pip install my-projectttttttt`, the installation folder:

```
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\my_projectttttttt
```

contains only the `__init__.py` file and the `__main__.py` file.

So where is my resource folder with my png? What am I doing wrong? I tried many different things (with or without `src` structure) with no luck and similar posts here didn't help me at all.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your project directory structure as it is, makes it so that your project has 2 top-level importable packages: `my_projectttttttt` and `resources`. The PNG file is effectively part of the `resources` top-level importable package, and not part of the `my_projectttttttt` top-level importable package. When you *pip*-install this project in this form, you should have a `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\resources` directory.

If I were you I would rather make it so that the `resources` package is a sub-package of `my_projectttttttt` and it is importable as `my_projectttttttt.resources`. For this you need to move `resources` as a sub-directory of `my_projectttttttt`: `my_projectttttttt/resources`. This would make a lot of things easier. You would probably also need to do some little adjustments in the `pyproject.toml` file, most likely the `include` and `packages` arrays should not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Your `include` statement in `pyproject.toml` is incorrect. The path should have the `/*` suffix, i.e.:

```ini
include = [
    { path = "src/resources/*" },
]
```

Comment: This would make it so that the project has two top-level import packages: `my_projectttttttt` and `resources`. Which is probably not what we should aim for as it is against conventions.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is the way the author's project is structured, and restructuring the repos folders is not always possible (e.g. when dealing with third party libraries, and aiming to maintain the original structure).